# Invalid URL when creating CosmosClient in javascript

Tags: javascript, azure-cosmosdb

I'm having a strange issue that when I try to create a client to connect to my CosmosDB, its throwing in an invalid URL error.

The code is simple and I know the keys and connection string are correct because in a different project I'm using them to connect with the DB in an Azure functions app (but that's in C#/.Net).  But for various reasons I need to create this in node.  I have tried creating the client with just the connection string and with the endpoint and key pass separately, both give the same result.

Here's my code -

```
const { CosmosClient } = require("@azure/cosmos");

const endPoint = "<obscured endpoint>";
const url = new URL(endPoint);
console.log(url.toJSON()); //this is here just to check the url since I was getting the error, and works fine


const key = "<obscured key>";
const connectionString = "<obscured connection string that encodes the endpoint and key>";
const cosmosClient = new CosmosClient({ connectionString });
```

This is error:

```
Uncaught TypeError TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
    at __node_internal_captureLargerStackTrace (internal/errors:491:5)
    at NodeError (internal/errors:400:5)
    at onParseError (internal/url:565:9)
    at URL (internal/url:645:5)
    at checkURL (c:\Web3Scan\Web3Scan\node_modules\@azure\cosmos\src\utils\checkURL.ts:5:10)
    at CosmosClient (c:\Web3Scan\Web3Scan\node_modules\@azure\cosmos\src\CosmosClient.ts:68:22)
    at <anonymous> (c:\Web3Scan\Web3Scan\app.js:16:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:82:12)
    at <anonymous> (internal/main/run_main_module:23:47)
```

When I look at checkURL.ts it looks like its doing the same thing as my test, so I'm stumped -

```
export function checkURL(testString: string): URL {
  return new URL(testString);  //same exact check i'm doing that's successful
}
```

Comment: This is a type error, and the `CheckURL()` function that's producing the exception expects a string. Given that you're working with `URL` objects, and you've obscured both parts of your code where you're passing those parameters, do you think it's possible that you're incorrectly passing an object and not converting it to a string?

Comment: No, I'm definitely passing a string all cases.  just a simple string in quotations.  And the string I'm using creates a valid URL just fine when I do the new URL(endPoint) call.

Comment: Or maybe I was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason your code is failing is because the `connectionString` parameter to `CosmosClient` is of type string [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/cosmos/cosmosclient?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-cosmos-cosmosclient-constructor), however you are passing it as an object.

Please try by changing the following line of code:

```
const cosmosClient = new CosmosClient({ connectionString });
```

to

```
const cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(connectionString);
```

And you should not get any errors.

Comment: That does remove the URL error, I could have sworn I tried pasting the string in directly before.  Of course, it still fails to create client, but at least there's some progress.